# Text Input not showing up in JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

I'm Writing this program to keep a log for a tutor. The purpose is to have a student "sign in" with his/her information. I have almost all of the code done except i cannot get the ADD button on the second frame to add the text input to the log. Here's what i have:

```
package gui;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class MainGUI extends JFrame {
   // Declare variables:
   // array lists
   String[] columnNames = {"ID", "NAME", "COURSE", "Professor", "Reason for Tutor"};
   Object[][] data = new Object[25][5];

   // table
   JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
      // sets the ability of the cells to be edited by the user
        @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
         return false; // returns false, cannot be edited
      }
   };
   // frames
   JFrame frame, frame1;
   // panels
   JPanel buttonPanel, buttonPanel2, tablePanel, addPanel, editPanel;
   // labels
   JLabel labelID, labelName, labelCourse, labelProfessor, labelHelp;
   // text fields
   JTextField txtID, txtName, txtCourse, txtProfessor, txtHelp;
   // buttons
   JButton btnAdd, btnEdit, btnDelete, btnSort, btnSave, btnAddInput, btnCancel;
   // additionals
   int keyCode, rowIndex, rowNumber, noOfStudents;
   // button handler
   ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();

   public MainGUI() {
      // setting/modifying table components
      table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new RowListener());
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(200);
      table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
      table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

      // main buttons
      btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
      btnAdd.addActionListener(bh);
      btnEdit = new JButton("EDIT");
      btnEdit.addActionListener(bh);
      btnEdit.setEnabled(false); // disables the component
      btnDelete = new JButton("DELETE");
      btnDelete.addActionListener(bh);
      btnDelete.setEnabled(false); // disables the component
      btnSort = new JButton("SORT");
      btnSort.addActionListener(bh);
      btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
      btnSave.addActionListener(bh);

      // with button Listeners

      // sub buttons
      btnAddInput = new JButton("Add");
      btnAddInput.addActionListener(bh);
      btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
      btnCancel.addActionListener(bh);

      // set label names
      labelID = new JLabel("ID");
      labelName = new JLabel("NAME");
      labelCourse = new JLabel("COURSE");
      labelProfessor = new JLabel("Professor");
      labelHelp = new JLabel("Reason for Tutoring");

      // set text fields width
      txtID = new JTextField(20);
      txtName = new JTextField(20);
      txtCourse = new JTextField(20);
      txtProfessor = new JTextField(20);
      txtHelp = new JTextField(20);
      txtID.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(15)); // limits the length of input:
                                                 // max of 15
      txtID.addKeyListener(keyListener); // accepts only numerals

      // main frame
      // panel for the table
      tablePanel = new JPanel();
      tablePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tablePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      tablePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 2, 0, 10));
      tablePanel.add(table.getTableHeader());
      tablePanel.add(table);

      // panel for the main buttons
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

      // positions the main buttons
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnAdd, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 1;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      buttonPanel.add(btnEdit, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 2;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      buttonPanel.add(btnDelete, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 3;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnSort, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 4;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnSave, c);

      frame = new JFrame("Student Database");
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
      frame.pack();

      // ADD frame
      // panel for adding
      addPanel = new JPanel();
      addPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      // positions the components for adding
      // labels
      c.insets = new Insets(1, 0, 1, 1);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      addPanel.add(labelID, c);
      c.gridy = 1;
      addPanel.add(labelName, c);
      c.gridy = 2;
      addPanel.add(labelCourse, c);
      c.gridy = 3;
      addPanel.add(labelProfessor, c);
      c.gridy = 4;
      addPanel.add(labelHelp, c);
      // text fields
      c.gridx = 1;
      c.gridy = 0;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtID, c);
      c.gridy = 1;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtName, c);
      c.gridy = 2;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtCourse, c);
      c.gridy = 3;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtProfessor, c);
      c.gridy = 4;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtHelp, c);

      // panel for other necessary buttons
      buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
      buttonPanel2.add(btnAddInput);
      buttonPanel2.add(btnCancel);

      frame1 = new JFrame("Student Database");
      frame1.setVisible(false);
      frame1.setResizable(false);
      frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame1.add(addPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame1.add(buttonPanel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      frame1.pack();
   }// end

   KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
        @Override
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      }

        @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

         if (!(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) && !(keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105)
                  && !(keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) && !(keyCode == 127 || keyCode == 8)) {
            txtID.setEditable(false);
         }
      }

        @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
         txtID.setEditable(true);
      }
   };

   class RowListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        @Override
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
         if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (data[rowIndex][0] == null || data[rowIndex][0] == "") {
               btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
               btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
               btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
               btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
            }
         }
      }
   }// end

   class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (e.getActionCommand().equals("ADD")) {
               // text fields for Student input data
               txtID.setText("");
               txtName.setText("");
               txtCourse.setText("");
               txtProfessor.setText("");
               txtHelp.setText("");

               frame1.setTitle("Add Student data"); // title bar name for add
               btnAddInput.setActionCommand("ADD");
               btnAddInput.setText("ADD");
               frame1.setVisible(true);

               }  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("EDIT")) {
               txtID.setText(data[rowIndex][4] + ""); // will preview the ID
                                                      // input during Add
               txtName.setText(data[rowIndex][1] + ""); // will preview the Name
                                                        // input during Add
               txtCourse.setText(data[rowIndex][2] + ""); // will preview the
                                                          // Course input during
                                                          // Add
               txtProfessor.setText(data[rowIndex][3] + ""); // will preview the Year
                                                        // input during Add
               txtHelp.setText(data[rowIndex][0] + ""); // will preview the
                                                          // Gender input during
                                                          // Add

               txtID.setEditable(false); // forbids the user to edit the entered
                                         // ID number

               frame1.setTitle("Edit Student data"); // title bar name for edit
               btnAddInput.setActionCommand("Edit2");
               btnAddInput.setText("ACCEPT");

               frame1.setVisible(true); // sets the visibility of frame1
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("DELETE")) {
               int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "ARE YOU SURE?", "CONFIRM",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

               if (confirm == 0) {
                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  rowNumber = 0;

                  noOfStudents--;
                  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                     if (rowIndex != i && i <= noOfStudents) {
                        data[rowNumber][4] = data[i][4];
                        data[rowNumber][1] = data[i][1];
                        data[rowNumber][2] = data[i][2];
                        data[rowNumber][3] = data[i][3];
                        data[rowNumber][0] = data[i][0];
                        rowNumber++;
                     } else if (rowIndex != i && i > noOfStudents) {
                        data[rowNumber][4] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][1] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][2] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][3] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][0] = "";
                        rowNumber++;
                     }
                  }
                  if (noOfStudents == 1000) {
                       btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                  else {
                       btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                   } // continues to add students if
                                              // not equal to 50
                  if (noOfStudents == 0) {
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                  } else {
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                  }

                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  if (data[rowIndex][0] == null || data[rowIndex][0] == "") {
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                  } else {
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                  }

                  table.updateUI();


            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {

               if (txtID.getText().isEmpty() || txtName.getText().isEmpty()
                        || txtCourse.getText().isEmpty()// /
                        || txtProfessor.getText().isEmpty() || txtHelp.getText().isEmpty()) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLEASE FILL IN THE BLANKS.", "ERROR!",
                  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
               }
                else {
                  int dup = 0;
                  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                     if (txtID.getText().equals(data[i][0])) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS.", "ERROR!",
                                 JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        dup++;
                     }
                  }
                  if (dup == 0) {
                     rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                     data[noOfStudents][4] = txtID.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][1] = txtName.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][2] = txtCourse.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][3] = txtProfessor.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][0] = txtHelp.getText();

                     table.updateUI();
                     frame1.dispose();
                     noOfStudents++;
                     if (noOfStudents == 50){
                        btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                     }
                        else {
                          btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                      }
                     if (data[rowIndex][0] == null) {
                        btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                        btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                     } else {
                        btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                     }
                  }
               }
               table.updateUI();
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Edit2")) {
               if (txtID.getText().isEmpty() || txtName.getText().isEmpty()
                        || txtCourse.getText().isEmpty() || txtProfessor.getText().isEmpty()
                        || txtHelp.getText().isEmpty()) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INCOMPLETE INPUT.", "ERROR!",
                           JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
               } else {
                  data[rowIndex][4] = txtID.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][1] = txtName.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][2] = txtCourse.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][3] = txtProfessor.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][0] = txtHelp.getText();
                  frame1.dispose();
               }

               table.updateUI();

            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Cancel")) {
               frame1.dispose();
            }

            }

      }
   }// end

   class JTextFieldLimit extends PlainDocument {
      private int limit;

      JTextFieldLimit(int limit) {
         super();
         this.limit = limit;
      }

      JTextFieldLimit(int limit, boolean upper) {
         super();
         this.limit = limit;
      }

        @Override
      public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr)
               throws BadLocationException {
         if (str == null) {
                       return;
                   }

         if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new MainGUI();
   }// end of main

}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Few people will be inclined to trawl through it. It's probably a good idea to narrow it down and post just the code relevant to the problem.

Comment: I agree. Try formulating a Short, Self-contained correct example. And check out http://sscce.org.

Answer (score 2):

OK, you've got a few problems here. I'll contain the fix to exactly how to fix the current issue, but you should break out your listeners into smaller objects that do different functions.

Problem #1 - You're re-setting the ActionCommand to the btnAddItem to "ADD" which will conflict with your btnAdd's command.

after line 71 where you create the btnAddItem, add the action command, and make it different (not just case wise) from the btnAdd item:

```
btnAddInput.setActionCommand("AddInput");
```

Then remove these two lines (around line 247), because they're not needed anymore:

```
btnAddInput.setActionCommand("ADD");
btnAddInput.setText("ADD");
```

Then we'll change your listener clause at line 326 to match. Change this:

```
} else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {
```

to:

```
} else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("AddInput")) {
```

Lastly, you've got a misplaced set of brackets.

Remove the close bracket } at line 391 (line right before //end) and add it in at line 325, right before this line:

```
} else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {
```

You're doing a bunch of other bad things - you shouldn't be changing ActionCommands, or having all this stuff in one ButtonHandler, but this gets you past your immediate issues.

Comment: Thanks man i was staring at this for hours trying to figure out why it wouldn't work. Also im a newbie to GUI so thank you for the tips as well.